# SVN: Accidentally deleted entire branches directory

Tags: svn

I was working on a remote svn repository that looked like this:

repository/

.trunk/

.tags/

.branches/

..branch1

..branch2

..branch3

And I accidentally deleted the entire branches directory!  What should I do to restore it?

EDITS:
I deleted "branches" from the repository browser in version #915.

Comment: Restore from your backup. You *do* have a backup, don't you?

Comment: I think so, but is there a way to do it through SVN?

Comment: In a working copy or in a repository?

Comment: Did you delete files inside SVN server system, or files checked-out from SVN as local copies?

Comment: It was deleted from within the repository browser, so I think inside the SVN server system.  I still have my local copy of one of the branches.

Comment: Did you try `svn cp ^/branches@914 ^/branches`?

Comment: Problem solved.  I used svn copy to solve it.  I will write up the answer in a second.

Comment: svn copy worked.  If you want to, post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reverse merge in your WC (of repo-root) revision 915: `svn merge -c -915` and commit
2. (???) Update WC to revision 914 and commit